# Scoring Algorithm in Model using a session variable in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, algorithm, session, rails-activerecord, scoring

I want to return results to a user sorted by a scoring algorithm that is personalized to the user based on their friends.  For context, in my app, users have events that they can add to their calendar.  Myevents is a join table between users and events.  I want to calculate a score based on how many total attendees there are to an event and how many of a user's friends are attending that event.

I want to do something like this:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

after_initialize :calculate_score
attr_accessor :score



  def calculate_score(user_id)


     User.find_by_id(user_id).friends.each do |friend|

                        if @id = Myevents.find_by_user_id_and_flier_id(friend.id, self.id)

                            friends_attending_list << @id
                        end

      end

    friends_attending_count = friends_attending_list.count

    total_attendees_count = Myevents.where(:flier_id => self.id, :attending_status => "1").count

     self.score = 100*(friend_attending_count) + 50*(total_attendees_count)

  end


end
```

Unfortunately, I can't find a good way to pass the session's user_id to the model....ideally, I would like to not violate MVC but I want to be able to sort results by this calculated score.  Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, to scale, you would need to cache this score somewhere. This method here would be veryyy expensive. But it's not a simple problem since it's a score per user per event.

I dont see how it makes sense to store the score on the event.

Without thinking of performances, I would have a `score_for_event(event)` method on the User model that you can call wherever you need.

Comment: Hey Robin-- thanks for your response!  I was storing them on the event because I wanted to be able to sort the events based on this parameter.  Could I do the same if I stored it on the User model instead?  Also, when you say caching it (sorry, this is one of my first apps), do you mean caching the action or actually storing it in a DB?

Comment: Right... I forgot the part about sorting... If you need the scores only for the events in the user calendar, then you could store this score in the Myevents model, and it would make your problem easier. You would need to update this score whenever a new user is attending an event (as a background job).